# on click highlight div

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events

I am trying to highlight a certain div by adding a class 'active' when it is clicked and remove the class 'active' from all the other divs that had was clicked with and have an active class.

Only one div can have the active class at a time

```
let i = 0;
    for (; i < list_wrapper.children.length; i++) {
        console.log(list_wrapper.children[i]);
        list_wrapper.children[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (this.className.indexOf('active') === -1) {
                this.classList.add('active');
            }
            if (this.className.indexOf('active') > -1) {
                // this.classList.remove('active');
                console.log(list_wrapper.children)
            }

        })

    }
```

Comment: Did you try it with [this.classList.toggle('active')](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper li').forEach(function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper li').forEach(x => x.classList.remove('active'));
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul id="wrapper">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `this.classList.remove('active');` without checking if it exists on all elements, then add it to the clicked one :

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

divs.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  
    // remove the class from the others
    divs.forEach(d => d.classList.remove('active'));
    
    // add the class to the current one
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  });
})
```

```css
div{
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  hello
</div>
<div>
  lorem
</div>
<div>
  world
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

from codeproject i try it work

```
$(".row").click(function () {
    $(".row").removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
--- CSS-- 
.highlight {    
    background: yellow;
}
```